# Change H3 to H2 with jquery keeping href and html elemens

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to change (just) the `h3` tag to `h2`, keeping all default html elements inside, this code are erasing all html contents !!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
        $('.sideMenu h3').replaceWith(function () {
        return "<h2>" + $(this).text() + "</h2>";
    });
});
</script>

<div class="sideMenu">
    <h3 class="sapanos">
       <span></span>
       <a href="#" title="Sainos">Sapanos</a>
    </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you tried `"<h2>" + $(this).text() + "</h2>"`?

Answer (score 7):

Use `.html()` to keep all the HTML structure. `text()` just gets the plain text, and throws away all the tags.

```
$('.sideMenu h3').replaceWith(function () {
  return "<h2>" + $(this).html() + "</h2>";
});
```

To keep the classes, do:

```
$('.sideMenu h3').replaceWith(function() {
  return $("<h2>", {
    class: this.className,
    html: $(this).html()
  });
});
```

---

Comment: Now i need to change h2 to h3, keeping the h2 class and html elements. eg.

<h2 class="myclass">html elements</h2>
to
<h3 class="myclass">html elements</h3>

TNKS !!!!!!!

Comment: It's the exact same thing, just interchange the tags. What's the problem?

Comment: My system is creating the h2 classes automatically, I do not have manual access to this html classes.

eg:

<h2 class = "apple"> </ h2>
<h2 class = "Banana"> </ h2>
<h2 class = "pear"> </ h2>

the classes are diferent...

Comment: Oh, you're asking how to keep the class when you change the element type?

Comment: Ok!! i got it !!! 

My code: 

  $('.smartMenuAdded h3:eq(0)').replaceWith(function () { 
        return '<div class="sapatos-femininos hasSubMenu">' + $(this).html() + '</div>';
    });

Comment: Now i need remove ( language="javascript" ) from javas called on head.
<script language="javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> to <script src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>.
How can i do that ? TNKS !!!!!

Comment: What does that have to do with this question? If you have a different question, post it separately. And why do you need to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in

```
return "<h2>" + $(this).text() + "</h2>";
```

Instead of `.text()`, use `.html()`.

`.text()` gets just the plain text content.

`.html()` gets the html content, which is what you want to transfer over.